# Modify ASP.NET TextBox generated html?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, rendering, doctype

Is it possible to modify the html generated by ASP.NET so that it automatically closes the input tag for a `<asp:TextBox>` currently it is generating the follow html code:

```
<input name="ctl00$txtTest" type="text" value="xxx" id="txtTest_0">
```

is it possible for it to generate the same but with a self closure tag as follows (note the forward slash at the end):

```
<input name="ctl00$txtTest" type="text" value="xxx" id="txtTest_0" />
```

Is the something i could do to perhaps force a specific DocType rendering or similar?

Comment: This will get you started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266988/render-self-closing-tag-in-asp-net-custom-control-derived-from-control

Answer (score 1):

This should work

Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Advanced > XHTML coding style
change to False
And then:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML (Web Forms) > Formatting > Tag Specific Options > Default Settings > Client tag does not support contents > Closing tag
change to No closing tag

after that debug again and check the generated source

Comment: Thanks for your response but it seems to render exactly the same when run?

Answer (score 0):

if you use Visual studio go by these steps
Tools ---> Options ---> Text Editor ---> HTML ----> Formatting ---> remove Auto insert close tag

Comment: Thanks for your response but it seems to render exactly the same when run?